# Timeout with 'service network restart'

Tags: bash, shell-script, networking, fedora, services

I have a script running on fedora 22 where I am restarting service network as part of a troubleshoot calling `service network restart`. I want to check if that command is taking too long to execute. If it takes too long I want to output a message saying "Error restarting network service". Else I want to continue with the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `timeout` command to run your command or script in a given timeout.
Something similar to this:

```
timeout 10m command
```

Which waits for the command to finish withing 10 minutes otherwise kills it and exits with status 124. Then you can check exit status of `timeout` and print the appropriate message based on it.
See here for more: [timeout manpage.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html)

If you don't want to kill the long command do something like this:

```
(( sleep $TIMEOUT; echo "command took so long!" ) & exec $COMMAND )
```

On TIMEOUT this will print the message but command continues to execute.

Comment: I don't just want to kill the script after a certain amount of time. I want to display a message. Will that make the script timeout at any point during it's duration? I just want that behavior during the time that 'service network restart' is running.

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about editing the original system scripts, inside the script you can create a function like

```
timeoutf(){
    #If hangs 1 minute, dies..
    sleep 1m 
    kill $PPID  
}

timeoutf&
```