# Run command after a certain length of time has elapsed?

Tags: shell-script, shell, delay

If I'm executing a long process, is there any way I can execute some time-based commands?

For example, I'm running a really long process which runs for roughly 10 minutes.

After 5 minutes, I would like to run a separate command.  For illustration, the separate command could be: `echo 5 minutes complete`

(Note: I don't want progress toward completion of the command, but simply commands executed after specified intervals.)

Is it possible?

Comment: Most of the times, you don't know in advance how long a process will take.

Comment: What do you mean "time-based commands"?  Do you want to create a progress bar?  Based on the current phrasing of your question, you could just put the long running command in the background and then display the system clock.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Wildcard I did clarify in the question. Not a progressbar. It will execute commands after some intervals

Comment: "5 minutes complete" is an odd thing to echo.  Not "5 minutes have elapsed"?  Not "The time is _____"?  Do you just want to ensure that some specified interval of time has elapsed from the time that your long-running command was started, before another arbitrary command is run?  If so, why not just run `longcommand & sleep 300 && command-to-do-after-five-minutes`?  (Actually that is probably what you are looking for.)  Note that your clarification wasn't sufficient, since you got two clock-progress-bar implementations right off the bat.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just run:

```
long-command & sleep 300; do-this-after-five-minutes
```

The `do-this-after-five-minutes` will get run after five minutes.  The `long-command` will be running in the background.

Comment: I usually use `sleep 5m && foobar`, so if I change my mind and ^C the `sleep`, the next command doesn't run.

Comment: @PeterCordes, when I tested it with e.g. `sleep 3; ls` and `^C`, the second command doesn't run anyway.  Not really sure why and maybe it works differently in a non-interactive shell?

Comment: @PeterCordes Not quite -- unless it differs per shell. When `sleep 5m && echo` is sleeping, when you suspend, only the `sleep` command is suspended. The rest of the command line runs, but since `sleep` got suspended, it did not exit successfully, and the part after `&&` is skipped. Try suspending `sleep 5 || echo hello`, and `hello` shows up directly after pressing `^Z`.

Comment: @hvd: Yup, you're right, and I'm wrong again >.<, using bash4.  Apparently it's been too long since I decided that && was the way to go as a ghetto `at(1)`, for stuff like `sleep 30m && mplayer something.mp3` alarm reminder, or for `sleep 90m && fg` to resume a disk-intensive command later.  So actually, `sleep 5m && echo hello` is nice because `^Z` suspends `sleep` without running the following command at all.  If you want to be able to suspend / resume the whole compound command, even before the sleep exits, use `( sleep 2 && echo hello )`.

Comment: @hvd: The `&&` idiom lets you be absolutely sure you don't kill the process right *after* sleep runs (because you can `^Z` to not run the command, instead of risking a `^C`).  This is useful in the `sleep && fg` or `sleep && bg` use-case, when the command being resumed is part way through something slow.

Answer (score 7):

There is a one liner for this:

```
( ( sleep $TIMEOUT ; echo "5 minutes complete") & $COMMAND )
```

In your case TIMEOUT=5m and COMMAND is the long command.

Also see my answer to this post [Timeout with 'service network restart'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285005/timeout-with-service-network-restart/285006#285006)

Comment: Launching a subshell in the foreground and then exec'ing the command seems needlessly complicated. I would remove the outer parentheses and the exec.

Comment: @glennjackman This way one can kill the whole procedure sending CTRL+C (for example) to the main (outermost) sub-shell.

Comment: But using exec, you don't have a subshell anymore, you just have the command. The command's parent is the shell running the script just as if you had not used a subshell at all.

Answer (score 6):

You could use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMPFILE="$(mktemp)"
STARTTIME="$(date +%s)"
(./longprocess; rm -f "$TEMPFILE") &
while [ -f "$TEMPFILE" ]; do
    sleep 1s
    NOW="$(date +%s)"
    if (( (NOW-STARTTIME) % 300 == 0 )); then
        echo "$(( (NOW-STARTTIME)/60 )) minute(s) elapsed"
    fi
done
echo "Done!!!"
```

It executes your `longprocess` in a `sub-shell` and then monitors previously created 'lock' file for existence.

Comment: Check `man bash` for `SECONDS`. You can set `SECONDS=0` at script start and only check for greater or equal to 300 or set `SECONDS=$((date +%s))` and forget using `date` again in your script...

Comment: @yeti, thanks for the hint, I did not know that.

Comment: @yeti, if you want to rely on the time after `sleep 1s` always being exactly one second later than it was before `sleep 1s`...then you have fallen victim to [Falsehoods that programmers believe about time](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).  (Although in this case, you might as well just show a hash mark progress bar or something.)

Comment: @Wildcard ... I did not mention `sleep` at all!

Comment: @yeti, right you are.  Thanks for the tip about `SECONDS`!  :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#! /bin/bash

( sleep 4 ) & # <-- The long running process.

seconds=1
while jobs %1 &>/dev/null ; do
    echo $((seconds++)) seconds complete
    sleep 1    
done
echo Done.
```

`jobs %1` fails once the job %1 has stopped.

Note that for longer times, $seconds might get out of sync with the real time. It's better to store the start time and compute the difference to the actual time.

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning one more approach using `at` command.

With commands like `play` and `notify-send` it can be used to have more visible, user friendly notifications:

- show notification popup with message
- play sound

```bash
# schedule notification
echo "notify-send 'Wake up!' && play ~/Music/alarm.wav" | at "now + 5 minute"
```

It'll look something like this:
[image]

---

**Note:** The `at` command has option to execute script file. Refer man pages for more features.
These packages may not be available by default in your distribution; so  you may have to install them manually.